# No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to use internet with the Android emulator, but with no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Use the browser or other applications on the emulator, or use internet connections in your own application?

Comment: Try to accept some answers, you and they will get reputation

Comment: This question has an answer that worked for a lot of folks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: I have answered below with URL which has more details!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If by "use internet", you mean you can not access the internet from an activity while testing on the emulator, make sure you have set the internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you are using the web browser, refer to Donal's post

Answer (score 111):

In order to use internet on emulator if you are setting behind a proxy server perform the following steps:

1. Go to settings->Wireless & networks->mobile networks->Access Point Names.
2. Press menu button. an option menu will appear.
3. from the option menu select New APN.
4. Click on Name. provide name to apn say My APN.
5. Click on APN. Enter www.
6. Click on Proxy. enter your proxy server IP. you can get it from internet explorers internet options menu.
7. click on Port. enter port number in my case it was 8080. you can get it from internet explorers internet options menu.
8. Click on User-name. provide user-name in format domain\user-name. generally it is your systems login.
9. Click on password. provide your systems password.
10. press menu button again. an option menu will appear.
11. press save.
    try n run your browser.

Comment: Not woking.. . .

Comment: It works for me!! Thanks a lot! The APN I had been trying to use is set to default "internet", but it turns out you need the value to be "www".

Comment: It worked me but without supplying username and password, I guess it depends on the network infrastructure. Thanks!

Comment: +1 works for with supplying username and password and yes it depends on network infrastructure

Comment: Not  working.... :)

Comment: fabulously working even with corporate proxy settings.

Comment: Works fine. I had to restart the emulator though

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer. +1

Comment: Thanks ! It works for me!!  proxy settings not required in my personal windows8 machine. use echo %userdomain% from cmd to know the domain which required to use as domain\user-name (step 8).

Comment: @includeMe,  @Kartiikeya Baleneni and if anyone else doubt if the proxy settings provided in the APN is working or not then go to @Dave Webb 's answer and follow the steps, after the emulator is running copy the log and find for the term called proxy, if you see something like "proxy not using", then you should start emulator with the following command to forcefully apply the proxy `emulator -verbose -avd <AVD name> -http-proxy http://username:password@host:port`

Comment: had to restart the emulator to reflect the changes made :)

Comment: On some API Levels you have to bring your device in airplane mode and back after saving the APN settings to apply the changes.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using eclipse try:

**Window > Preferences > Android > Launch**

Default emulator options: `-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

Comment: We are not using eclipse anymore. We are using Android Studio? How to do this on Android Studio?

Comment: command line: `emulator -avd Pixel_C_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

Comment: adding -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 to my emulator command line solved the issue for me. Android had no internet before, now it has. Running on Win10. I'm puzzled why that command line argument was necessary though?

Answer (score 18):

Try launching the Emulator from the command line as follows:

```
emulator -verbose -avd <AVD name>
```

This will give you detailed output and may show the error that's preventing the emulator from connecting to the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

Check your internet settings, firewalls and such may be blocking it, I know when I was working on it in college they were blocking the port number but I've never had any trouble on my home machines

Comment: what port is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you run into this problem and are working with a non-Windows/Mac OS (Ubuntu in my case), try starting the emulator by itself in Android SDK and AVD Manager then running your application.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to  follow these steps:

1. run android emulator 1.5
2. open up the menu
3. go to settings
4. wireless settings(first block) and right at the bottom turn off airplane mode.

By now you would've seen on top 3g and your established connection.

Answer (score 0):

on OSX, Little Snitch was automatically denying any connection to Eclipse (and the emulator). Allow connections in Little Snitch, you have to go into Little Snitch's rules

Answer (score -2):

Allow the ADB to access the network by opening it on the firewall

If you are using winvista and above, go to Windows Advance Firewall under Administrative tool in Control Panel and enable it from there

Comment: this image does not exist

Comment: downvoted until image is restored.

Comment: down voted because image is not available.