# How to make Android Emulator access web when my PC is on WiFi

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just realized that my emulator can't access the web.
My computer runs on WiFi and perhaps the emulator isn't able to detect it.

how to get it working?
emulator isn't running on Airplane mode.
Please help.

Comment: check if your router or firewall are blocking the emulator

Comment: It should work, this is an issue with your computer. This is better asked at the new android stackexchange or superuser

Comment: I heard that F12 can turn the network on in the emulator, but i'm not 100% sure. Also, try to change settings related to network of the emulator.

Comment: @Sheikh Aman: Emulators have no problem with WiFi. I use that configuration rather frequently. When the emulator starts up, it attempts to contact some server, and if it can't, it pretends to be offline. As Vuk indicates, your problem may be with a firewall, or a proxy server.

Comment: @ Vladimir That key is F8 which toggles 3G.
@ CommonsWare, @Vuk Strange, i still can't get it to work, everyone else here says that no firewall/proxy is being used! :-(

Comment: Okay, what if a proxy is being used?? then what do i have to do?

Comment: I am not getting it to work!! :-(

Comment: here is how to start the emulator with a proxy - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#proxy. Try out a few more topics on that page that you think might be related.

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077910/emulator-unable-to-connect-to-internet

Comment: Okay i recently figured out that some ports are blocked on my computer, and only few of them are opened.
So is there any specific port that Emulator wants to be open?
Please tell

Comment: @John.. yaa, it is a duplicate.. sorry, but i want more hits on it to get it answered as soon as possible. plz!

Comment: @Falmarri: This is actually about Android development, so it is more appropriate here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched long and hard for an answer to this question. From what I gather Google prevented emulators from accessing the internet on purpose once people started using emulators to add spam comments to the market. However, [I did find a guy who had done it and was willing to share the required images.](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html)

**NOTE**: It looks like it's just going to fix the market.  But the market won't run without internet, so if the market is fixed, the browser internet will work too.  I downloaded the linked files myself and it showed the internet in the browser perfectly.

Comment: Okay i recently figured out that some ports are blocked on my computer, and only few of them are opened.
So is there any specific port that Emulator wants to be open?
Please tell

Comment: Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/

Many of the ports of the public server that serves us the internet are blocked. may this be a reason? if yes, then which ports i have to get opened?

Comment: I don't know which specific port it uses but the linked emulator WILL run internet.

Comment: That's what.
And as the ultimate solution, I am switching to Ubuntu. feel more comfortable developing with it.
Am equally sad as I couldn't find the reason behind it.

Comment: That's what. That's what i used to believe! but it isn't working with my current config, anyhow. Trying to move to Ubuntu as the ultimate solution.

Comment: @Sheikh Aman:  Glad to see you got it working.  It will increase your reputation if you accept an answer(other than your own).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Wifi, simply disable the lan adapter from your control panel.

I had the same issue it seems the emulator connects to lan by default.

Answer (score 0):

Magically, i disabled the USB WiFi dongle and switched to a cable connection, and it started working! don't what the reason was, but for now, I am staying with Windows 7 to save some time I would have been spending in installing things on Ubuntu.