# Connecting android app with sql database?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I tried this example for connecting with database, i have simple database, and this is the java class:

```
package com.cvele.android.sqlconn;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SqlconnActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
        rootLayout.addView(txt);  
        setContentView(rootLayout);  
        txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
        txt.setText(getServerData(LINK_PHP)); 
    }
    public static final String LINK_PHP = "http://10.0.2.2/sajt.php"; 

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair>nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1970"));

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(LINK_PHP);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                    ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                    ", sex: "+json_data.getString("sex")+
                    ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );

                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return returnString; 
    }
}
```

and this is the php:

```
<?

$databasehost = "127.0.0.1";
$databasename = "peopledata";
$databaseusername ="nikola";
$databasepassword = "nikola";

$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear >'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");


if (mysql_errno()) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $query.'\n';
    echo mysql_error(); 
}
else
{
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

So when I build this, it always just write something what is between " " in string LINK_PHP ="http://10.0.2.2/sajt.php". I can't get any data from my database. My question is, why it is always written that on my app ..? Thanks in advance.
this is what I get:
[image]

Ok, this is what I get in LogCat:

```
04-11 16:02:33.064: I/dalvikvm(811): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-11 16:02:33.256: I/dalvikvm(811): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-11 16:02:33.544: I/dalvikvm(811): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-11 16:02:33.604: I/dalvikvm(811): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-11 16:02:33.724: E/log_tag(811): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-11 16:02:33.724: E/log_tag(811): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 16:02:33.744: E/log_tag(811): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-11 16:02:33.944: D/gralloc_goldfish(811): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-11 16:02:34.044: I/dalvikvm(811): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-11 16:02:34.104: I/dalvikvm(811): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: If you work in emulator check with WireShark if you actually receive them from your server.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot run your `NETWORK` activity on the same thread (from the newer versions of Android SDK).
2. To do so, go ahead by implementing `Asynctask`. It will handle all your task even considering memory too.
3. There is `Runnable` thread too but go through the `AsyncTask`.
4. Get the input stream. make a `while loop` to read stream and `append` it with `String`.
5. Now, if you've XML, then go through parsing the XML by `Document` object. For this, go through `DocumentBuilderFactory`. (example for xml).
6. Now, get your data from `Document` (instance in object **doc**) object like something `doc.getElementByTagName("yourxmltaghere")`;
7. However, if you're with JSON then, hold your `JSON`. If it has child objects, then make `for` loop till the `mArray.length` and then fetch your data one by one.

Above, you said `Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`, it means you're trying to CAST your XML to JSON. So, I don't have your `CASTING` code here. However, I did this by the following way.

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = 
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
} 



String xml = sb.toString();                         
JSONObject baseObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);

JSONObject todo_items = baseObject.getJSONObject("todo-items");
JSONArray todo_item = todo_items.getJSONArray("todo-item");
tempItems = GenerateVO(todo_item);
```

Here, `XML` is the class, I loaded. I didn't found any other so used this. I got this class from `org.json` package provided by `JSON`. Go through google to have it or get from here.
[XML LINK](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java)

Answer (score 1):

Consult the LogCat output. Think, you'll see a message about the exception there.

Using Eclipse you can open the LogCat output with Window>Show View>LogCat.

According to this line

```
Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

you've targeted your app to Honeycomb or later. The [exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is thrown because you are performing network operations from the main (GUI) thread, which is strongly prohibited :)
Try to target your app to API level 10 (Gingerbread) just to try your code. But further move your network operations to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I see, I added LogCat...Can you explain a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: It would have some sense if he'd put something into logs, not only errors.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

Comment: Thanks Roman, I'll try it. :)  Artem I cheked, internet on my emulator is working, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I tried, same thing happens... Any other suggestion? Now it says in LogCat this: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Now check the value of `result` variable before creating a `JSONArray` instance (e.g. with dumping it to LogCat too). It contains your server response and must be a valid JSON. If not, you have problems on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Again, check the actual received HTTP message: seems like you get XML instead of JSON.

Comment: or you could post the content of response you get from your server connection. Add the "is" content  to your question.