# How can I get internet on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I get internet on android emulator? Now my emulator browser not working properly...

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to connect android emulator to the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Comment: @Andro Selva, I can't get internet using emulator Browser.

Comment: Can you see a 3g symbol at the top right corner of your emulator? If not, press f8 key in your keyboard. It toggles between internet on and off.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix

Comment: @AndroSelva, I pressed F8, now I got 3G symbol; but still no use...

Comment: Hi every one, please have a look this picture [link](http://i.imgur.com/P3PQ2.jpg?1) of my emulator. Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to when you're on a wireless network,  and also you have wired network card in your system. This issue occur when, emulator tries to obtain its DNS settings from wired network card card and it fails to get information. To solve this disable wired network card and try again.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a wifi network to access internet. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

For ur emulator from home select go settings->wireless & network.click airplane mode. Make it disable by clicking again. (If airplane mode is active then u can see a airplane symbol in emulator top most bar.. otherwise an wireless symbol will appear.). If u have any wireless connection then u can go to Wi-Fi network options..

Comment: If u have internet in the device i.e PC where u r running the emulator.. then it will get the connection form PC. That time u can just change the options through settings.

Comment: I tried this, but no use. I'm using a wireless network. Internet works fine in my laptop. ie I can connect to internet with the help of web-browser (Mozilla). Android emulator's browser is not connecting to internet.

Comment: Hi every one, please have a look this picture **[link](http://i.imgur.com/P3PQ2.jpg?1)** of my emulator. Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be two of this cases:

1.- You did not insert the internet permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2.- The configuration of the Network Connections in, for example, Eclipse, are wrong or lost. Please, review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet) post to know how to set it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I'm not running any application project in my emulator. The thing is that, I just opened emulator by using AVD manager and click on browser icon in the menu. It's not connecting to internet.....

Comment: Try to made a new virtual device and test if in the settings of the device are enabled the wireless connections.

Comment: Hi every one, please have a look this picture **[link](http://i.imgur.com/P3PQ2.jpg?1)** of my emulator. Thank you....