# Emulator only have internet connect if opened by CMD

Tags: android, emulation

i havent changed anything and the weekend passed by and then back to work my emulator doesnt connect the internet, it only does if i open by CMD with this:

```
cd AppData\Local\Android\androi‌​d-sdk\tools>emulator -avd emulator_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

so i want to know if anyone is having these problems aswell because i dont want to keep opening it from CMD every single day. ( and i guess that is not only me)

OBS: Creating a new Emulator doens't work(internet connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below link, here you will have some detail about the internet connectivity.....

http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html

OR

[No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

This may help you.....

Comment: my server (where i get the internet from) doesnt have a proxy (my boss said as im at work) D: