# Android 2.2 Emulator can not connect internet but 4.0.3 emulator can connect

Tags: android, android-emulator, internet-connection, android-2.2-froyo

When i try to connect internet with android 2.2 from emulator can not connect. But, if i try to connect internet with 4.0.3 from emulator immediately i will success..

I have changed from eclipse, configurations, proxy settings, network settings, ip numbers, dns settings and the other settings but it is same.

In addition this, i have changed from all settings android 2.2 emulator, settings->wireless&networks->mobile networks->access point names->myconnection
but again it is same.

However, all these problems are not on android 4.0.3 emulator.

What could be causing this? Does anyone have any ideas? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

in  settings->wireless&networks->mobile networks-> Data enabled (Checkbox)

keep it as true

Now check it............

Answer (score 0):

please see the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix) and if it does not works for you,restart the emulator or create a new android 2.2 version emulator.

Comment: thanks. but i have tried all these. the problem that is android emulator 2.2 can not connect and emulator 4.0.3 can connect also same settings, same conditions. but how?