# Getting error "process com. android.setting" while surfing interent on android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am trying to use Internet on my Android emulator. When I open browser I get Error **"No Internet connection"** . 
When i go to settings ->wireless & network -> mobile network, I get  "**The application setting "process com.android.setting**" has stop unexpectedly." error

Can any one suggest me solution for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Note : I am not working on any application. I am just trying to open the default browser of android emulator.

Logcat :

```
12-26 14:31:37.688: D/AndroidRuntime(481): Shutting down VM
12-26 14:31:37.688: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7f0)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.phone/com.android.phone.Settings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:828)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:190)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3401)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4662)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:879)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:637)
12-26 14:31:37.707: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 14:31:37.717: W/ActivityManager(75):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.WirelessSettings
12-26 14:31:37.817: I/SurfaceFlinger(75): 
12-26 14:31:37.817: I/SurfaceFlinger(75): SurfaceFlinger::createSurface() : layer->mIdentity=68, LayerName= Sorry!
```

Comment: @UsmanKurd i edited my question with logcat. Also i am not running any kind of application just accessing the normal browser in emulator.

Comment: have you declaired your activity in manifest File ?

Comment: Usman Kurd is correct, declare your activity in Manifest

Comment: Please read my comment again i am not working on any application. I just opened the emulator select the browser and i am getting all above errors.

Comment: by default emulator uses your machine (laptop/ computer) WIFI setting and it should work

Comment: Took a look at the following https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/X3D7s4cmXcQ

Answer (score 0):

Try, open AVD manager -> your emulator -> Edit.-> Hardware->New->GSM Modem Support.
If still not working then

**No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?**   [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

**How to connect android emulator to the internet** [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Comment: I tried it many times and also reinstall the add-ons also but no luck