# Internet not working in android emulator in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I am using android studio 2.2 in windows 10(64 bit) operating system,
My problem is my android application is not working in an android emulator(internet issue), My emulator is working fine I have opened a browser and checked with sample links too then I have confirmed that the internet is coming to an emulator. But here my problem is when I run my application it was crashing saying that it was unable to connect the internet
My Logcat file is:

```
11-23 12:30:35.800 11061-11333/com.vave.getbike E/Application: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to videos.meritcampus.com/192.34.59.210 (port 9000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                                                           com.vave.getbike.exception.GetBikeException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to videos.meritcampus.com/192.34.59.210 (port 9000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helper.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:11)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.BaseSyncher.handleException(BaseSyncher.java:28)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.JsonPostHandler.handle(JsonPostHandler.java:31)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.LoginSyncher.signup(LoginSyncher.java:37)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.activity.SignupActivity$1.process(SignupActivity.java:52)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:37)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:18)
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to videos.meritcampus.com/192.34.59.210 (port 9000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                               at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.utils.HTTPUtils.getDataFromServer(HTTPUtils.java:99)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.JsonPostHandler.handle(JsonPostHandler.java:25)
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.LoginSyncher.signup(LoginSyncher.java:37) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.activity.SignupActivity$1.process(SignupActivity.java:52) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:37) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:18) 
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                            Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
                                                               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 
                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452) 
                                                               at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.utils.HTTPUtils.getDataFromServer(HTTPUtils.java:99) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.JsonPostHandler.handle(JsonPostHandler.java:25) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.syncher.LoginSyncher.signup(LoginSyncher.java:37) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.activity.SignupActivity$1.process(SignupActivity.java:52) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:37) 
                                                               at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:18) 
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

11-23 12:30:35.873 11061-11100/com.vave.getbike E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4b44f0
11-23 12:30:35.909 11061-11061/com.vave.getbike D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-23 12:30:35.909 11061-11061/com.vave.getbike E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.vave.getbike, PID: 11061
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.vave.getbike.datasource.CallStatus.isSuccess()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.vave.getbike.activity.SignupActivity$1.afterPostExecute(SignupActivity.java:58)
                                                                      at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.onPostExecute(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:72)
                                                                      at com.vave.getbike.helpers.GetBikeAsyncTask.onPostExecute(GetBikeAsyncTask.java:18)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

please help me in this regard:
I have already given internet permission in manifest file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>     i have already added this permission access in android manifest.xml file

Comment: I think problem is your url should contain http://

Comment: Thanks for the response @Abhishek, but the same application was working fine on mobile device(mote e)

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix

Comment: No use @Priya Jagtap, I already saw that post

Comment: "Connection timed out" means there's a connection with the server, but the server doesn't respond. Have you tried connecting with a test program, like with Restclient?

Comment: Hi @Christine, but the same application was running correctly on a mobile device means getting the response from server, why the same application was not working on emulator

Comment: Did you test the connection with the server using Restclient or a similar program?

Answer (score 0):

1st try "Cold booting" emulator as suggested here.

If cold booting doesn't work, try changing the DNS address of your network to 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) or another of your preference:

Mac:

Open "System Preferences"
Click on "Network"
Select the network which your computer is connected and click on "Advanced"
Select "DNS", Select the "+" button, type "8.8.8.8" (Google's DNS)
Select "Ok" and "Apply"

Windows & Ubuntu:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

After that re-start the emulator.