# How to set Internet options for Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've been using this method to gain access to internet from my Android emulator
emulator `-http-proxy <<proxy-name>> -avd <<avd_name>>`

It works but is that the best way to do it?
It just doesn't feel right that I need to open the emulator from command line and can't just do it from Eclipse or something.

Can't seem to find an internet option on the "AVD Manager" either.

Comment: In my case, mobile data was not enabled in settings http://stackoverflow.com/a/21464099/1176454

Answer (score 58):

You could also try explicitly specifying DNS server settings, this worked for me.

In Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Comment: this fixed the issue for me where the emulator would only get net on some wifi networks and not others. 'emulator -avd adv_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4'

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio => Options => Xamarin => Android Settings => Additional Emulator Launch Arguments

Answer (score 23):

By default, you should be able to toggle the Internet access to your emulator with F8 (on Windows) and Fn + F8 (on Mac OS X) - I think F8 also works for Linux, but I'm not 100% sure.

With this shortcut, you get the [ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED)  dispatched.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When Internet connection is available with emulator, F8 is helpful!

Comment: This gave no visual or any other kind of feedback, but after restarting the emulator (recreating the virtual device, actually), it had internet access.

Answer (score 7):

for the records since this is an old post and since nobody mentioned it, check if you forgot (as I did) to set the android.permission.INTERNET flag in AndroidManifest.xml as, i.e.:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.webviewdemo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".WebViewDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

-http-proxy  can be set in eclipse this way:

1. Menu Window
2. Submenu Preferences
3. In Preferences Dialog
   Click Android in left part
   Click Launch
   Near Default Emulator Options: input ur -http-proxy

Answer (score 4):

Add GSM Modem Support while creating AVD in your virtual devices from Android SDK and AVD Manager...

Answer (score 3):

It was setting the DNS that did the trick for me. If you are using the Eclipse or Netbeans plugins, you can set it through Default Emulator options, or Emulator Options respectively. You can also use set it from the command line if you start your emulator from CLI. In all cases, the option is "-dns-server x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x" without the quotes. There is no option in the ADB gui to permanently associate the option with your virtual device.

Answer (score 3):

Hi me also faced same issue , solved using below steps:

#### cause 1:

Add  internet permission in your android application

#### cause 2:

Check the manually your default application is able access internet or not
if not its problem of your emulator , check in your internet connection in your pc

try below method to connect net in your pc

try explicitly specifying DNS server settings, this worked for me.

In Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4**

#### cause 3:

check : check if you are using more than one internet connection to your pc like one is LAN second one is Modem ,
so disable all lan or modem .

Answer (score 1):

delete the existing one and recreate the emulator.
The machine(windows/mac) should have internet access,and android emulator gets internet access by default.

Answer (score 1):

If someone have a Internet Permission in AndroidManifest and still have a problem with Internet Connection, maybe that will be helpful:
[Android - Fixing the no internet connection issue on emulator.](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html?showComment=1344511892100#c5603712472032022102)

I followed steps from that website, and everything works for me.
The most important:

- Configuring the proxy server on the emulator
- Incorrect DNS Used by the Emulator

That is my first post, so I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On a slightly different note, I had to make a virtual device **without GSM Modem Support** so that the internet on my emulator would work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen various suggestions how code can find out whether it runs on the emulator, but none are quite satisfactory, or "future-proof". For the time being I've settled on reading the device ID, which is all zeros for the emulator:

TelephonyManager telmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
boolean isEmulator = "000000000000000".equals(telmgr.getDeviceId());

But on a deployed app that requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using AVD Manager, choose Tools -> Options. Set HTTP Proxy Server to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

The emulator will be connected.

Comment: That's Google's DNS servers, not a proxy server.