# Error :: The URL could not be found

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can not open browser in my Android Emulator, It gives Error like this,

```
onReceivedError -2 http://www.google.com/ The URL could not be found.
```

Can anyone tell me how this resolve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, after running for a while, the Android emulator looses it's internet connection for no apparent reason. Restarting the emulator fixes the problem.

Comment: I had also done that but no result. Is there any settings to resolve this problem..? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access) for some other tips.

Comment: delete and recreate the emulator.