# Exception with Internet in Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I try to use internet in my app (Android version 3), I add to manifest necessary permission, but this code doesnt work:

```
    private void qwer() throws IOException{

        DefaultHttpClient d=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get=new HttpGet("http://google.com");
        HttpResponse r=d.execute(get);
    }
```

It always throw exception. I use emulator, version Android - 3.

```
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:481)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:281)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.dad.aaa.Qwerty11Activity.qwer(Qwerty11Activity.java:42)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.dad.aaa.Qwerty11Activity.onCreate(Qwerty11Activity.java:31)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-07 16:23:27.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the network request in the UI thread. This results in blocking the whole UI. In this case [StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) caught it and threw you an exception to tell you that this is bad. Move the networking code into a seperate thread. A useful tool for this is the [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You might also want to look into [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Implement a separate thread for a network call from Androd 4.x onwards.  Use one or more of the following for threads AsyncTask, IntentService (it creates seperate worker thread), Handler.  Try to avoid using java threads.