# Custom URL scheme Android

Tags: android, url, custom-action

Hi custom url scheme is not working for me. Here is my code

```
                <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="jinilabs.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

when I type the url on the emulator browser - http://jinilabs.test 
It is giving me web page not available error.
Is there anything wrong here? Plz let me know

Answer (score 3):

Simply typing the URL into the bar won't do it. Your url needs to be a clickable link on a webpage because the browser method that checks if it's a custom url only fires when a link is clicked; it simply runs url's that are entered in the address bar(and ignores custom urls).
Clicking [this link](http://jinilabs.test) should launch your app as it is now. If it still doesn't work, you may need additional code in your manifest file. Mine looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="appcall.thing"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".AppCallActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="stoneware.app.switcher" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Of course, you will have to substitute some of the names in here for names relative to your app. I would also recommend starting your url scheme with something unique rather than http in case the http is confusing the browser. My url scheme, for example was stoneware.app.switcher://
Hopefully this can be of some use to you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post, I suspected it after hour of looking for solution why it does not work from browser url.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and then try.

Comment: hi Ravi, I have added that also. but even though it is not working

Comment: Please refer these answers : 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access 2.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix

Comment: Hi Ravi, the above links didn't help me out. My internet is working fine and i am running on samsung nexus S.