# Android SDK Java: not found

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, java

A few days ago I started with Ubuntu for the first time. I want to use Android SDK with Eclipse. I installed everything needed. It only goes wrong when I try to start the Android SDK. There is a proxy server on the internet here, but when I try to insert it at:

Eclipse > Windows > Preference > Android > Launch and then enter the proxy in Default Emulator Options  (link: [How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access))

Each time I start the SDK via Eclipse, I get failed to fetch with... so I found out that I can enter the proxy via the android tool. But when I enter ./android-sdk-linux/tools/android I get some errors:

./android-sdk-linux/tools/android: 84: java: not found
./android-sdk-linux/tools/android 101" java: not found
exec: 114: java: not found

I installed the JDK from oracle. I followed the steps and it did install via the terminal. After that I added it to the PATH(maybe I did it wrong here). I tried it with the JRE too. Eclipse gave an error at the begin about java. But when I installed a copy of the JRE in the Eclipse folder, it didn't give an error anymore.

So I think it's my JDK, but I don't know what I did wrong.

I use Ubuntu 11.10. 64bit via VMware Player.

Comment: @Kimi /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/<user_name>/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/<user_name>/jdk1.6.0_29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [path from comment]
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home//android-sdk-linux/tools:/home//jdk1.6.0_29

Change the path of your JDK in $PATH to `/home/<user_name>/jdk1.6.0_29/bin`.

Comment: I did **export PATH:$PATH:/home/<user_name>/jdk1.6.0_29/bin** but it said **not a valid identifier**

Comment: That's because you missed the identifier: export PATH=$PATH:/home/... (use `=` instead of `:` after `export PATH`)

Comment: thx for your help. I had the PATH wrong. It doesnt give an error now. Just some things and some fails. Now I have to setup the proxy right :/

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu I had to go into the /sdk/tools/android and change the java_cmd variable to equal my JAVA_HOME path - then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and fixed it. I'm running Debian based Linux Distribution. And my setting $PATH variable environment didn't work even thought I can run java from Konsol.

Here is another better solution.

[Linux Ubuntu Android SDK manager not starting up - android:java: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441928/android-sdk-manager-not-starting-up-androidjava-not-found/17418841#17418841)

Solution which I mean is, make a symbolic link /usr/bin