# Linux Ubuntu Android SDK manager not starting up - android:java: not found

Tags: java, android, linux, ubuntu

I extracted the android SDK into a folder i made called "/usr/android/android-sdk-linux". I go into "tools/" and double click the executable file "android", click "Run in Terminal" but nothing happens. I also click "Run" but again nothing happens. i run it in terminal (`./android` command), and i get:

```
./android: 1: ./android: java: not found
./android: 1: ./android: java: not found
./android: 110: exec: java: not found
```

So why is this happening?

**Edit:** Here are the results of `~$ java`

```
* default-jre
* gcj-4.6-jre-headless
* openjdk-6-jre-headless
* gcj-4.5-jre-headless
* openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All i had to do was `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. Never trying a manual installation again. oh and sorry for my ignorance on the previous answers.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've edited your answer I hope it is correct,worked for me that way, I thinnk it was a typo

Comment: Same problem. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

when you are using Debian based Linux Distribution, the better solution if you install JDK manually (not from repository) is by make a symbolic link that point to a java command.

I solved this problem. Create a **symbolik link** named **/usr/bin/java** dan point it to **/home/your_name/your_jdk_folder/bin/java**

This is the sample command in terminal/konsol

```
sudo ln -s /home/azware/tmp/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: that worked in my Ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse kepler. But it's going to be impossible to remember to change this symbolic link every time i update my JRE. There must be an .ini file in eclipse that holds this setting instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Sun JDK 1.8 in /opt/jdk I solved this problem with this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/java java /opt/jdk/bin/java 0
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/bin/javac 0
```

This uses the Debian-based alternatives system that Ubuntu also uses. Please note that this is in the case that you don't have any other Java (i.e. OpenJDK) installed. If you have another Java installed, chances are you already have an alternative installed for it. Consult the update-alternatives man page to see how the system works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have java installed. Try just running `java` - is that not found?

Comment: java is installed... look above to see the results of `java`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the Java6 **JDK** in particular, installed.

Comment: I have jdk 7 on... does it have to be 6??

Answer (score 0):

I was using android studio on ubuntu 14.04, 64bit and this error was caused due to the file permission issues in `$home/android-studio/sdk/tools`

```
$sudo chmod -R 755 ./*
```

Running the command in `$home/android-studio/sdk/tools` solved the problem.