# Hitting XML Service from Proxy network

Tags: android, xml, web-services, proxy

I am currently working on Android application, I am unable to connect to Internet from my Android Emulator since my company has proxy settings -- I need to provide username and password for connecting to Internet.

Any suggestions how to get XML data from proxy network where i should provide username and password?

Comment: Supply the emulator with an appropriate [`-http-proxy <proxy>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) option when starting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check these answers
[How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access)
[No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)
[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)