# Getting internet connection in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, connection

I have a desktop pc with wifi connection.My ip address is 192.168.12.95 and gateway is 192.168.10.10 .But i am not getting internet connection in the android emulator.That is i can not able to acess internate.
I have also try with " emulator -avd wbut -http-proxy 192.168.10.10:3128 " this command.
But sometimes i get the connection in the emulator without doing anything.

Can someone please tell me how can i get internet connection in my android emulator ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/how-to-set-internet-options-for-android-emulator)

Answer (score 5):

Click F8 key after starting emulator. F8 used for Turning network on / off.

Comment: If I off internet in emulator using F8, then first dialog appers for no internet access and still my native browser open websites. Just check it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

In Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

In the Default emulator options, put the value

> -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

If this does not work, check this post
[How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2437366/1244489)

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a internet access then you have to nothing to do to get internet access in emulator. Emulator get internet connection automatically if your system has.. Just check you emulator for AirplaneMode or hit url in android native browser to check internet connection..