# Unable to create Emulator for android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to create an emulator by choosing emulator-x86.exe from tools folder. Whenever I created I'm getting the below error, and emulator is not getting created. Whats is the issue?

> Ant build error=Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "${emulator.dir}\android.bat" (in directory "ECLIPSE_PATH\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\370\1.cp\emulators\android"):CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Please help me friends

Comment: why don't you use AVD manager to create AVD.

Comment: If AVD Manager fails, reinstall.

Comment: @Santhosh To access the network in emulator im trying like this. and i tried creating emulator using AVD  manager but wifi is not getting connected in the emulator. Can you please help me how to use wifi in emulator?

Comment: does your application require wifi? if yes, then FYI check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067389/1567588 (you have to use a real device for that.) if you are just trying to use the internet available in your laptop? then, check network connectivity in that emulator, it might have airplane mode on and goto wireless and network settings and switch on the wifi.

Comment: @Santhosh network connection is required to my application. I'm trying to connect the wifi from my desktop. I do remember that i connected with wifi from my laptop to emulator. Here, i'm using business network and trying to connect with wifi from my desktop, its not getting connected

Comment: Check out these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191876/1567588 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2702663/1567588, http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html?showComment=1344511892100#c5603712472032022102, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941189/getting-internet-connection-in-android-emulator

Answer (score -2):

you can follow this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/) or 
do like this

```
hw.lcd.density=252
sdcard.size=32M
skin.name=NEXUS-ONE
skin.path=platforms/android-10/skins/NEXUS-ONE
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.keyboard.lid=no
abi.type=armeabi
hw.keyboard=no
vm.heapSize=24
hw.ramSize=256
image.sysdir.1=platforms/android-10/images/
```