# Warning: no dns servers found

Tags: android, android-emulator, dns

I want to access internet in my android emulator for which i have manually entered dns setting as mentioned in the following link 
[How to set Internet options for Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access)

but still when i start the emulator it show the warning that no dns server found and hence there is no internet connectivity in my android emulator. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4736518/1050058)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse:

Window>Preferences>Android>Launch

Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above method, but had no effect unless setting a name-server on the host OS (Linux):

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces 

auto eth0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```