# Android AVD not connecting to our server

Tags: android, eclipse, connection, ddms

so I am one team member on a small project and we are using a Git repo so have identical code. The application was working fine and I think I may have done something to eclipse but I'm just not sure.

The problem is *My* version of the app does not connect to our server any longer (basically for logging in).

- It works fine when I use my actual phone.
- It works fine for my friend on his machine using the emulator through eclipse or his phone.
- Our code is definitely identical
- I have tried changing the default emulator options as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access) answer
- I recently updated the developer tools through the SDK manager, it might have broken around this time but I don't think so.
- It actually seemed to happen after I pulled a new version for the code from Git so I blamed my friend :D, but if it works on my phone, and works fine for his emulator and phone then I am sure there is no problem with the actual code.
- Also I have checked the Emulator Control tab in DDMS and this has data set to home and latency at none (the defaults)

Any ideas on what I could try?

Edit: Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet) suggestion, I have disabled any Ethernet LAN adapters and am just connected directly to the router wirelessly

Comment: Maybe it's your internet connection problem? :D Or you can try to pull project grom git to see notable differences.

Comment: Na internet is fine and router etc. is untouched. I was thinking maybe Windows 8 installed some update and was blocking it but I doubt that would be the case right?

Comment: You looked indications of the network manager? It can be any system process