# No internet access on Android Emulator, Shared Internet Connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-internet

I have Installed Eclipse Juno and Updated the ADT as well to 22.0, I have created a custom AVD of Android 2.3 version as is working fine, but it seems there is no internet connection on my Emulator,

Note: It also shows the 3G symbol on the title bar. Look the image of my emulator given below.

Also worth noting, I connect to Internet via DSL internet cable right into my NIC card, and I also share my internet via wifi with my room-mates via connectify pro Hostspot. In this situation there is no internet connection on my Emulator.

But when I connect to the shared Internet of my friend's Connectify hotspot then it works fine.

I want to resolve this issue, I think it's because of sharing the internet connection.

[image]

Comment: did you add the permission to use internet in your manifest?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I know this, but I m testing the internet connection on default browser of android emulator, I dont have any app to send any HTTP request to internet or somthing like that.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib I m not getting you, what does it mean, will you please elaborate it a little.

Comment: @QadirHussain Is your internet connected through a network proxy server set by your network administrator? See your connection settings. If yes then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/android-emulator-internet-access?rq=1

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib Yes its a proxy server may be, I not sure. I just know i have provided an internet cable by a internet network system owner, When i connect it to my PC it assigns an IP automatically to my PC and Internet is avialbe on my PC, this is what i Know.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib What should i see in connection settings?

Comment: I want to resolve this issue, I think its because of sharing the internet connection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I sorted out my problem.

It was problem due to dns server address.

I did below steps

1. open CMD
2. Goto your android-sdk/tools path, Like my path is `G:\Andriod Development\android-sdk\tools`
3. type this command `G:\Andriod Development\android-sdk\tools>emulator.exe -avd Android_2.3.3 -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -scale 0.75`

here Android_2.3.3 is your AVD name, -dns-server 8.8.8.8 will set your DNS address to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.8.8:55 and -scale will scale your AVD to specified value.

this will start a new emulator. 
Enjoy :)

Hope may be helpful to others

Comment: @Pradeep only once. but if you close the emulator , again you have to start the emulater via this command

Comment: This is the only one answer that worked for me. You saved my life

Comment: Glad to hear this helped :)