# Android Studio - Android emulator default browser.Browser crashed and cant connect to internet

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, internet-connection

Newly created APN with proxy and port

[image: Newly created APN with proxy and port]

Emulator configuration:

[image: Emulator configuration]

Browser stopped message:

[image: Browser crashed]

Unable to access internet:

[image: Unable to access internet]

I want to access internet in Android studio emulator, for that I have created a new APN with necessary proxy and port settings, but cant access internet inside emulator.

Kindly help me to find my mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: what's inside My APN?

Comment: Name - MY APN , APN - WWW , Proxy - XXX.XX.X.X, Port - XXXX , other fields are default

Comment: when you use the original "T-mobile us" do you have the crash?

Comment: you have internet problem with Android emulator, first make sure to close and restart the emulator, then go to your emulator settings make sure in network,  full speed is checked.

Comment: Network speed is full only @MounirElfassi

Comment: try this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252278/no-internet-access-on-android-emulator-shared-internet-connection?answertab=active#tab-top