# Android emulator keeps losing internet connection after a few minutes of running

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

When I start up the android emulator, I have internet working on the entire device (all apps have internet access, my own included). Unfortunately within 5 minutes of running, the device looses it's ability to connect to the internet.

***Example Usage***

1.Boot Device (boot completed at 09:00)

2.Open Firefox

3.Start using the internet
   - Internet works fine. I visit 4 different sited in this time.

4.Internet becomes very slow (first noticed at 09:03)

5.First error message happens at 9:05

[image]

6. From here on out I cannot connect to the internet until I reboot and start the process all over again.

I have tried creating entirely new system images to make sure it is not a configuration problem with one particular emulator setup, but that did not help.

Though many similar questions have been asked before, I was unable to find a solution to this problem. Any insignt you might have is appreciated. If there is anywhere I can go for more detailed logs, please point that out too.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with DNS

Are you using wireless? Is your LAN adapter connected? You may want to disable it so adb doesn't try to use it for DNS
[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Otherwise, try explicitly passing a DNS server to the avd at startup:
`emulator.exe -avd INSERT_AVD_NAME_HERE -dns-server 8.8.8.8`
[No internet access on Android Emulator, Shared Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252278/no-internet-access-on-android-emulator-shared-internet-connection)