# AVD emulator ver 24.4.0.0 network connection not working

Tags: android, networking, android-virtual-device

I am trying to use an AVD to test a phone app that needs to be able to use a network function.

The in-emulator browser does not work, even if I put an ip address into the address bar instead of a URL.

Are the stock AVD images setup with Android Studio 1.4 shipped with the network function disabled?  It doesn't seem like it would be reasonably appropriate to have to setup a proxy where I don't use a proxy for normal networking on my win7 development desktop unless that was the design, and the documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html don't exactly mention you *have* to use a proxy.

Comment: use apache server or others for local urls.

Comment: @Taquir, not sure what you mean.  'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' both show connection_refused in emulator's browser, that could be some helpful if apache server were a proxy server.  is that what you mean?

Comment: No. use any web hosting server preferred apache or xamp or wamp. follow their documentation to host any website. check your url in browser. if it is working there then in emulator also it will work.

Comment: @Taquir I have a website running on IIS, 'localhost' works from desktop browser, a 192.168... works, both show the IIS hosted website.  192.168... does not load the website/page in the AVD emulator's browser

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437366/how-to-set-internet-options-for-android-emulator   OR    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet