# Loading information from API

Tags: android, api, wolframalpha

I'm using the Wolfram|Alpha API and I'm trying to load the results in HTML format inside my view. I've got a EditText where you enter you're query and an enter button. When you're query is entered I want the requested information to load underneath the EditText and such.

The code is a bit long so I've put it in a text file here.

https://sites.google.com/site/jstheelements/extrafiles

And here I have the LogCat of results from where I press the enter button that can be found on that same link. I know that the System.out.printIn needs to be changed. At least I believe it does. The problem is I don't know where to go from where I'm at. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your question should say something about wanting to resolve com.wolfram.alpha.net.WAHttpException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.wolframalpha.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: FYI, the appid that you changed in the code to XXXX... is shown in plain text in your logcat output. You'll probably want to change the apilogcat.txt file as well to scrub those references.

Comment: If you're deploying the app to an emulator, are you able to use the web browser to access any websites, e.g, google.com?  If not, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet and try searching for similar issues.

Comment: @Marc Bernstein thanks. I didnt realize that.

Comment: @Thane Yes I'm deploying to the emulator. I am able to get to websites just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and realized I didn't have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>;
```

in my Android manifest file.