# Web Browser in Android Emulator not Working

Tags: android, browser, emulation

For some reason I can't connect to the web using the browser on my Android 2.3.3 emulator..
Are there any setting that I must set up first before I try this or am I missing something?

Thank in advance!

Comment: See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: You have to check your Proxy setting

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse you must do next:

1. Go to Window-->Preferences
2. Check in Android-->Launch

In Default Emulato Options type "-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4" (without quots)

Or start Emulator from command line. Next will be Linux commands:

```
emulator -avd google_8_api -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -scale auto -dpi-device 195
```

Hope, it helps you