# How to connect android device with local network

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using android 2.2 for application development.

Now I want to communicate with web service. The web service is running on my laptop and IP is `192.168.1.15`.

But device not communicate.

How to communicate with local network?

Comment: Clarification needed. Are you running this from a handset or the Android Emulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to connect android emulator to the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Answer (score 1):

[From inside the Android emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses), your laptop is actually `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: I think he was testing with a real device, not the emulator. (not my downvote btw!)

Answer (score 1):

try to pass 192.168.1.15/yourwebservice in device web browser. If it does not runs, then you should switch off your laptops firewall.(if using windows OS).

And if it runs then there might be some problem with ur application.
Paste code in that case for further help.