# Android: How to connect my android emulator to the internet?

Tags: java, android, emulation

I use Windows 7 and my emulator that is not connecting to the internet. No browser opens to any link. I need to make my emulator to run web applications. I have given already the internet permission into the manifest tag. Also i have disabled and enabled my LAN connection. After doing this, i got my emulator once connected to the internet. there after it is not getting connected.

Comment: does your network have any Proxy settings?

Comment: go through the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: check  setting of  proxy and port in emulator right or not??

Answer (score 1):

you need to restart/re-launch your emulator every time if your internet get disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the dns might work.
I changed it to Google's dns server.

This is how I did it:

Eclipse:
**Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch**

Default emulator options: `-dns-server 8.8.8.8:55 ,8.8.4.4:55`