# internet is not connected to emulator on android

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my emulator internet is connected. i am using USB Modem , no proxy used. i have disabled LAN card and in windows firewall i add emulator program as exception programs but no use. still internet is not connected on emulator. i added a screenshort and referred link:

[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: yes i have seen the link. as told in the link i disabled the lan card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem. i have just disabled the wireless network and restart the emulator its works.