# Android emulator loses internet connection after a period of time

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having trouble with the android emulator, this one is Android 2.3.3 but i've had trouble with other versions as well.

When i start the emulator everything works great, for a while. But at some point (I don't know how long) it just stops working and i have to restart it.

It happens every time, and restarting it always fixes it. I've tried toggling the network on and off but that doesn't help.

The exception I get in logcat is "java.net.UnknownHostException: foo.com"

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here.  The network connection lasts no more than an hour usually.

Comment: @Hong yep, that's my experience

Comment: I found a solution (ie disable lan card) in [another so thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2702663/874502).

Comment: [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077852/4515489) seems to have found a possible cause of the issue, though not a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this link while researching the same issue. The DNS server fix worked for me.
http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work, i still lost my connection after a little while when setting -dns-server