# Android : can't load my XML file and app crashes

Tags: android, xml

So I just created a parser and a handler to parse an XML file. It works fine in my Java test project but doesn't in my Android project. Here is the complaining log :

> 07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ec.ec/com.ec.ec.ListeOffresActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at com.ec.ec.ListeOffresActivity.onCreate(ListeOffresActivity.java:31)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):   ... 11 more

It appears that my emulator isn't connected to the Internet, right ? What should I do ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: check this forum post for a lot of answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running your `Network request` on main UI thread. use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to execute network request.

Comment: make your `Network Request` in `doinBackground` of your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

The  log is not very cleay. But I can see the below error -

07-12 09:44:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)

So most likely the URL is not accesisble from emulator, as you are able to access and parse the XMl from your java code.

Can you launch the browser from your emulator and see if the URL or even the internet is accessible?

-dattatray.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and no, Internet isn't accessible.