# Android emulator Internet connection in my application

Tags: android, permissions, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with my android emulator on my mac. I can use the browser and load websites so there is an internet connection in my AVD.
My application can't connect to the internet, I am aware of the manifest configuration and I have set the internet permission on.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The application works well on several devices but never worked on the emulator.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Omri.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to localhost?

Comment: on which `emulator` you are testing? OS?

Comment: I am trying to connect to a website on the internet, not to my localhost. I tried several Android OS in the AVD. 2.2 2.3 4.0 none worked.

Comment: Are you on a wireless network? If so, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: I am using a wireless netwrok. I checked out this post and tried to disable my lan card. It didn't help. I tried to add the  -dns-server 8.8.8.8 so it will use googles DNS servers, It didn't help either. I think that if I had DNS problems I wouldn't have succeeded browsing the internet with the android browser.

Comment: What address are you trying to get at?

Comment: are u on any proxy connection?

Comment: No I didn't use a proxy connection.

Answer (score 1):

Preferrences->Launch settings to Default emulator options: -dns-server
and use https on url.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, James Elsey's question turend me in the right direction.
I was trying to reach my own server with a ssl certificate. For some reason the emulator doesn't like my rapidsssl certificate and the connection is timedout. It does work on android devices though.
Because the emulator is only for developing I can change the configuration and work with http only without ssl.

Thanks everyone.