# No internet access in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, internet-connection

I am not able to access internet in my emulator. It doesn't even connect to google on emulator browser. I have already checked Settings. Data Enabled checkbox is checked.

I referred to a few SO questions before posting the question.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2702663/1777090) suggests, I don't have wifi enabled. So that doesn't seem to be a problem.
As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3998795/1777090) in the same question suggests, I tried giving it in Run configurations, but still nothing is changed.

If someone can give any idea, that will help me a lot.

Note: On my emulator's home screen, 3G appears, but its with grey lines. I think those lines should be white. I might be wrong on this.

Comment: were you connected to the internet before starting the emulator?

Comment: Yes. I was connected before starting emulator

Comment: I've had that happen a couple of times myself, just closing the emulator and re-loading usually fixes it

Comment: That also didn't work in my case.

Comment: Though marked negative by only three, but has solved the problems of many users here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add GSM Modem Support to your emulator.

open AVD manager -> your emulator -> Edit.-> Hardware->New->GSM Modem Support.

Comment: check mobile data is enabled or not in emulator.

Comment: Check that second link I have provided in my question. That gives same solution. Unfortunately, that also didn't work in my case :(

Comment: Well, I have checked the "data enabled" in settings. It shows the symbol of 3G on home page with gray lines.

Comment: which api level your emulator uses?

Comment: have you added GSM Modem Support.?

Comment: Where? In emulator settings?

Comment: yes.open AVD manager -> your emulator -> Edit.-> Hardware->New->GSM Modem Support.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Can you please edit your answer to include last comment, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @NiravTukadiya I am facing a similar issue, but can't find AVD manager -> your emulator -> Edit.-> Hardware. API level 25.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for http proxy settings in Tools of android sdk Manager in Eclipse.

Comment: What should I give as proxy?