# internet issue on emulator for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Download Eclipse with ADT ver 23.0.2. Internet is not working.

Tried -

```
Run > Run Configurations 
Pick the "Target" tab
Scroll down to "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" > -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

But internet is not working and showing disconnected.

thanks

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696562/1777090). It had helped me.

Comment: Have you run any apps using internet in that emulator?

Comment: Do you tested in your emulator browser??

Comment: run app which uses internet but message "no internet"...

Comment: have you added internet permissions to manifest ?

Comment: yes.   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: @user2717440 : Are you using pc with proxy settings enabled? may be that is blocking your connection. can you post your logcat