# google map api V3 did not display on android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm doing a school android project. One of the function that i had implemented is the google map api v3. However it did not display on the android emulator. But it works on the web. Can anyone tell me when i when wrong in my coding. Much appreciated. The codes for the map is below.
     
     
     
     Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and add these two lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to bridge the emulator's network device?

[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Above post may help. To check, try running Browser and Google Map app in your emulator and make sure they connect

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebView in your application, you need to add android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest.

Check first if it works in the browser, like Ankur said.