# How to communicate from android emulator with server which has not registered in DNS

Tags: android, android-emulator, connection, image-uploading, image-upload

I am uploading image from android emulator to server(which is not registered in DNS) using php script. But I got the following error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /Upload.php was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at "SERVER NAME" Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I have done entry of server name and IP address in host file c:\Windows\System32\ect\hosts. I try to open same URL from browser and it is working, Then why it is not working in emulator?

I am also facing same problem while downloading image from same server, How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referencing the IP address of the server directly in the script?

Comment: Does the emulator browser correctly show the page? If not see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12085995/747322) to set up the networking on the emulator

Comment: I am able to send and retrieve textual data from same server but not able to download and upload image on that server.

Comment: Emulator browser is not showing page but my PC's browser can show that page