# Connect Android Emulator to Internet Windows Vista 64-bit

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I'm kinda desperate. I have been trying to connect the Android emulator to a network and have tried every single suggestion form other blogs and questions. I'm connected directly to the network without a Proxy server.

I tried:

- Default emulator options

  > -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
- Run Configurations with my IP

  > -dns-server X.X.X.X
- Setting APN in the Virtual Device:

  > Since I'm not connected to a Proxy, I guess this won't be an option.  But I tried just to be sure.
- And many other suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet).

Does anyone have any other suggestion or a possible solution for this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated, will save my day!
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your PC, if so turn it off. Also any logcat from the browser showing how the emulator isn't connecting to the internet would be helpful.

Comment: I just set the APN in my virtual device "NAME: mynetwork", "APN: www", and the rest of the entries "not set". Its working now, I don't understand!