# Enable Internet Access on Android Emulator using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a Mac OSX v10.9.1 running Android Studio. I am connected to WiFi. I have a web container in my program that doesn't load. I have tried using Fn + F8 but no success. The 3G is displayed when i pressed Fn + F8 but there is still no internet connection in the emulator.

Comment: you can go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet/3998795#3998795. It may helps you..

Comment: i am not behind any proxy

Answer (score 2):

For Mac Users

Go to Mac "System Preferences" and click on "Network"

Click on the gear icon on the lower left corner

select "Set Service Order"

Bring the active interface before other interfaces (Bring it down the queue)

Restart the Android Emulator.