# Genymotion "mobile network not detected"

Tags: android, genymotion

Hi I read this question: [How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

I made sure my permissions in AndroidManifest.xml allowed for an internet connection
I disabled my LAN to only use wireless
I enabled my LAN card and plugged into the LAN

I still get the message when my app tries to launch a phone call.

Comment: making a phone call isn't possible with an emulator: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making a phone call isn't possible with an emulator: developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html