# Android emulator can not connect to internet

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I have installed eclipse but when I launch the Android emulator it shows an error that it can not connect to internet. I'm using eclipse in my laptop and it is connected to WiFi but the emulator can not connect to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect android emulator to the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Answer (score 0):

1> I recommend you use GENYMOTION. It is the fastest android emulator. It is easier to rectify errors if they exist.
DL Link : https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

2> Also to rectify the error you just stated; make sure you have set the internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3> Goto

```
 ...\android-sdk-windows\tools>
```

and write the following and check

```
emulator -avd your_avd_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

don't forget to close your previously running AVD, before applying these steps.

Try any of the 3 steps.