# Web service response not getting on emulator but getting in browser and on mobile device

Tags: android

I am calling REST API from my android application using HTTP URL Connection, but i am always getting socket `timeout exception` when i am running app in `emulator`. 
I am getting the response when the API is accessed in `browser`. Also when i am running my app on mobile device i am getting response over mobile data.
Is there any settings while accessing API's on `emulator` (**any kind of proxy settings**)

I have tried the below code but still getting socket timeout exception.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("hostname", port number));
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Please Help.

Comment: make sure in your emulator, you are able to access internet.

Comment: Actually i checked that as well. i am not able to access internet on emulaor . So this can be the issue?? If yes, what i am supposed to do?

Comment: check this link. May be it would be helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: But i am getting response on emulator when i am connected to data card but don't get response when connected to the Ethernet connection. So, **No internet access** to the emulator can't be the problem i guess.