# Why does the emulator in Android Studio refuse to connect to the internet?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

For some time now, the emulator I'm currently using has refused to be connected to the net.
Now, the PC is connected via WiFi and is browsing. Initially I thought that since my PC is connected then the emulator should be, but this is not happening.

I have also switched on the WiFi in the emulator but it is not seeing my hotspot. Don't know why though physical devices can see same hotspot.

Please How do I connect the  emulator to the internet.

Android Studio  version is 2.11

**AVD Details**

```
Name: Nexus_7_Inch

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\RosyK\.android\avd\Nexus_7_Inch.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: nexus_7_2013

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 7 2013

vm.heapSize: 64

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

hw.camera.back: none

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_7_Inch

hw.camera.front: none

hw.lcd.density: 320

runtime.scalefactor: auto

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 7 Inch

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:47dc70fd92541dd16c19f9efa3e9db62

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: no

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: what are your AVD details ?

Comment: @Shubhank, I have updated the question

Comment: was it working previously in the same AVD or it never worked ?

Comment: @Shubhank this is the first time I'm using it.

Comment: Then you should post all AVD details like API - version and your system OS

Comment: @Shubhank, I have updated my question.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: lot of solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: @Shubhank this may be right but these are solutions for a 5 year old emulator... And another note - the new Android Studio 2.0 emulator doesn't support WiFi [Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html).

Comment: true but i would still post it here since if we get a definitive answer, we should move it to that thread since that will be the best place for everyone to get help in future. On other note, Android emulator do suck with internet connection. I fixed mine but i don't remember how lol.

Comment: It still is not connecting even when I am using a modem

Comment: maybe you should use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as an alternate ?

Answer (score -1):

**add this to your manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Have done that sir, the app that I'm testing is connecting on a physical device.