# access internet from 127.0.0.1 and one port for all packets

Tags: networking

i got a network problem. network  packets (maybe tcp,udp and so on,i cann't control) can only access 127.0.0.1 on port 6666 (maybe),how can i forward these packets to the Internet?  because these packets may communicate with  outer servers,so i need route them someway,i guess.

Comment: You can use SSH port forwarding, but it can only forward packets from port 6666 to a single port of a single host.

Comment: in fact ,i want to run app ,which will communicate with it's Internet servers ,in android studio emulator, but  android studio emulator has isolation,it can access 10.0.2.2 ,which map 127.0.0.1 of my localhost

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: i tried, this solution solve http access ,not meet my situation,thank you anyway