# How to allow emulator in Android Studio to access internet?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to test an app that uses internet and location. But the emulator seems to have no internet access.

I am pretty new, please ignore my restating the obvious. If someone can help with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet)

Comment: @Prem thanks. but I'm able to figure it out. The laptop wifi is connected to my mobile's hopstop (motorola g4). is there a simple solution? not being rude, I've been searching for this for 2days now

Comment: " but I'm able to figure it out" you ARE or are NOT able? this says you are.  Please edit your question to provide more detail, what you have tried etc. to improve the question quality.