# Android Emulator Advanced network settings

Tags: android, xamarin

I have to debug a c# application for Android that use a socket to connect to a desktop pc using an UDP connection.
The problem is that from the Emulator I can't setup the network. I tried enabling WiFi but no emulated WiFi was available.
Is it related to the emulator version 25.2.5-3567187 currently not updated to the latest version  26.1.1-4333796 (Stable update channel) for the missing tools as explained here ?

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123402/the-avd-manager-visual-interface-is-not-available-for-your-version-of-sdk-tools-26-1-1-please-use),

Is there a workaround to setup a connection between emulator and other device in the same network?

Also why in emulator setting (...) there aren't advanced options.

Comment: I suggest you use physical device to test wifi function.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DNS to google's 8.8.8.8. You do that by long press the Network you're connected to, and tap Modify Network. Try changing IP settings to Static, instead of DHCP.

If that doesn't work try disabling the network card of the PC.
Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet).

Answer (score 0):

About the AndroidWiFi I tested that is available only on the Android SDK Tool version 26.1.1-4333796. So in Visual Studio if you want use the android emulator, I suggest to use the last Android SDK Tool version (instead of 25.2.5-3567187) with the Xamarin Android Device Manager.