# Flutter NetworkImage doesn't load the URL

Tags: image, flutter, url, dart

[image]I am learning Dart on Flutter.
I am trying to display an image from a URL using `NetworkImage('URL')`, but the picture is not displayed on my emulator, here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Test()));

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('This is a title.'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image(
            image: NetworkImage(
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/25/13/12/dog-2785074_960_720.jpg'),),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Click'),
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[900],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error log:
[image]

Comment: It looks fine, are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: @JideGuru I just added a screenshot.

Comment: please change MyApp into Test in this error class

Comment: Well where did you define the MyApp() widget?

Comment: I changed it, thank you. But I suppose it has nothing to do with the NetworkImage() widget, since nothing changedon the emulator.

Comment: can you show the `Output` instead of the `Problems` tab?

Comment: @JideGuru here you go.

Comment: It seems there is not error in the console as far as i can see. 
Check if you are connected to internet on the emulator.

Comment: I checked, the Wifi is on (Connected), but when I open up Chrome, which is the first time I did, it keeps checking info.

Comment: UPDATE: I couldn't sign in, I receive a message : Couldn't sign in to Google servers.

Comment: It's your internet then. Find a way to fix the internet and you problem will be fixed

Comment: @JideGuru yes, or to be more specific, it is my LAN adapters that are the source of the problem; I am on Windows 10, and connected via wifi, however, I have my Lan card enabled, which was the source to my problem.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet), I found the solution to my problem. Apparently, having LAN card enabled while you are on a Wifi network is the source of the problem.
I had to disable every network adapter that is not used except for my wireless card, and voilà. 
Thank you, everyone, for taking the time to look into this problem, I hope this might help someone with the same problem.