# Flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

I am new in Flutter. I face a problem about `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException`.

Here is my Debug Console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(10702): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:59535/02E90npmd4s=/ws
E/flutter (10702): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(network_error, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null, null)
E/flutter (10702): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
E/flutter (10702): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (10702): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10702): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:356
E/flutter (10702): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10702): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:244
E/flutter (10702): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10702): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter (10702): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10702):
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is caused when you are not connected to internet. Check your internet connection and try again.

1. Check if you have added INTERNET permissions in the androidManifest file.
2. From the logs I can see that you are using [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) so make sure you have uploaded the SHA-1 to the Firebase console. If not then add the SHA-1 key and replace your google-service.json file with new one.
3. If running on an emulator check if the emulator can access the internet. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20Android%5CSdk,8.8%20command%20and%20press%20enter.).

Comment: I checked the Internet, the Internet is stable.

Comment: I uploaded the SHA-1 key and replaced my google-service.json file with new one, but the problem still here.

Comment: @MyCar is it a release version or debug version apk and is it running on a emulator on real device?

Comment: It is a debug version apk.

Comment: It is running on a emulator on the computer.

Comment: So check if the emulator can access the internet. There's the problem. Made an edit on the answer. If it solved then do accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried Everything then Found this Solution by myself

1. Open Settings in your Emulator
2. Then Open Location settings
3. Click on "Apps Access to Location"
4. Select your App from the List of other apps asking for location permission
   5.Select any of the First Two Options.

Tested Solution

Answer (score 1):

google is rejecting your request because your API is not enabled,
enable maps SDK for android and IOS, then add your API key in the AndroidManifest.xml[image: as shown in the image]