# Firestore PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: flutter, macos, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, apple-m1

i have this problem on macOs when i code my flutter App,
The same base code work in my windows pc but in macOs it don't work.
As you can see in my logs, the application is connected but I still cannot make a request on my Firestore database

I changed the rule which was

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

but i have the same error.

```
D/FirebaseAuth(11790): Notifying id token listeners about user ( tNGS8j375AYehEPDhZADPP80zLY2 ).
W/DynamiteModule(11790): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11790): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11790): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/Firestore(11790): (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(usersProDEV where uuid == tNGS8j375AYehEPDhZADPP80zLY2 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (11790): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

The same code work in my windows PC

Comment: There is some useful information written in this article, [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404), that might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several I realized that the problem was not only under MacOs but with emulators. And by digging further I realized that it is AppCheck that I activated on the project which does not accept all the requests of the Debug mode under the emulator.

Comment: Please i have the same issue with my emulator on mac, how did you solve it? where did u solve the problem on your pc

Comment: I disabled AppCheck

Answer (score 4):

According to this [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94301), there is an error with your app accessing the internet. Please check your network connection:

> Check that you have the proper internet permissions in the androidManifest file (suggested by Abhishek Dutt).

> If you are using an emulator, check if the emulator can [access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20Android%5CSdk,8.8%20command%20and%20press%20enter.) using this post.

**1st edition:**

Can you please try this example code from this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) for authentication:

```
  service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /messages/{document=**} {
          allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
      }
    }
```

This code must work only for reading and not writing:

```
   service cloud.firestore {
        match /databases/{database}/documents {
         match /{document=**} {
           allow read: if true;
           allow write: if false;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: thank for your response, at the same time, the connection is made via otp verification which opens a web page for the verification by captcha with firebase auth, after i put sms code which verify and I receive the token that you see in the console but get data via firestore is there that there is the problem.

Comment: Added some codes to my answer, could you try them

Answer (score 3):

Inside `projectFolder/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` add the following:

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: thank you but I added but it didn't change the error

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    // Set androidProvider to `AndroidProvider.debug`
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,   );
```

Your app will print a local debug token to the debug output when Firebase tries to send a request to the backend. For example:

```
D DebugAppCheckProvider: Enter this debug secret into the allow list in
the Firebase Console for your project: 123a4567-b89c-12d3-e456-789012345678
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYD2O.png)

In the App Check section of the Firebase console, choose Manage debug tokens from your app's overflow menu. Then, register the debug token you logged in the previous step.

[Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYD2O.png)

After you register the token, Firebase backend services will accept it as valid.